# Json.NET crashes when serializing unsigned integer (ulong) array

Tags: c#, javascript, json, json.net

Getting a parser error when trying to serialize a ulong array, looks like the Json.NET library isnt checking if the integer is signed or unsigned;  any one know of a workaround for this? or any other .NET Json library that can handle unsigned int's?

**EDIT: code below; **
It serializes fine, but when its deserializing it throws an error;  Looks like it doesnt cater for the unsigned int from looking at the stack trace;

```
NewTonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException : {"JSON integer 18446744073709551615 is too large or small for an Int64."}

Value was either too large or too small for an Int64.
   at System.Number.ParseInt64(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
   at System.Convert.ToInt64(String value, IFormatProvider provider)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseNumber() in d:\Development\Releases\Json\Working\Src\Newtonsoft.Json\JsonTextReader.cs:line 1360
```

```
   class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new ulong[] {ulong.MinValue, 20, 21, 22, ulong.MaxValue});
                Console.WriteLine(output);

                ulong[] array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ulong[]>(output);
                Console.WriteLine(array);

                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is the exact error you're getting? Can you also post the stack trace, along with relevant bits of your code?

Comment: It's probably your code.  Why don't you post it?

Comment: Last but not least, I've found it useful to tell you that the DLL from net45 doesn't have this problem, whereas the one from portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81 have it... I changed my project references to target the net45 only, and the problem disappeared. But if your app is a wp one, you're stuck...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're right, JSON.Net doesn't handle values larger than `long.MaxValue` in this case.

I didn't find any way to modify that behavior, except by modifying the source code of the library. As a workaround, you could deserialize it as `decimal[]` and then convert that into `ulong[]`.

Comment: Yes sadly it seems to be a limitation in JSON.Net, I think your solution of casting it to a decimal[] will have to do for now, thanks a lot :-)

Comment: @svick Could you please share what exactly were your modifications to JSON.Net to allow ulong round-tripping (and breaking the Json standard)? I also need a version of the library that does this.

Comment: @OmerRaviv Sorry, I don't have that code anymore (and I'm not sure I ever had, it's possible I just looked at the code, but didn't actually modify it).

Answer (score 10):

[ECMA-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), the standard on which JSON is based, specifies in section 4.3.19 that number values are IEEE double-precision floating point values, commonly seen as the "double" type in C-like languages. This encoding is not sufficiently precise to represent all possible values of 64 bit integers.

Therefore, encoding 64 bit integers (signed or otherwise) in JSON may lead to a loss in precision if it passes through any code which processes it in keeping with the standard. As seen in JSON.net, it might also break code which does not correctly implement the standard, but rather assumes that people won't try to do failure-prone things.