# Json.net DeserializeAnonymousType returns BigInteger instead of UInt64

Tags: c#, parsing, json.net, biginteger, uint64

Suppose we have the following code:

```cs
Type t = typeof(UInt64);
var def = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
Console.WriteLine(def.GetType());

string json = "18446744073709551615";
object parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, def);
Console.WriteLine(parsedObject.GetType());
```

The output is:

```
System.UInt64 
System.Numerics.BigInteger
```

Since I explicitly fed `DeserializeAnonymousType` with `def`, type of which is `UInt64`, I would expect also `UInt64` as an output, especially since 18446744073709551615 is a valid `UInt64` value (max value, granted, but I checked also with 18446744073709551614, it is same).

Why is it so? I checked Newtonsoft Github issues, and found nothing (at least, not in open issues).

How can I force the correct type which I know in advance (dynamically, I have only `System.Type`)? Obviously, if it happens only for `UInt64` I can make a check and cast explicitly.

Comment: See if this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9355091/json-net-crashes-when-serializing-unsigned-integer-ulong-array#11978882) helps at all.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks! It helps, but the thread states that json numeric values are "IEEE double-precision floating points". That would mean that even Int64.MaxValue would not be okay, but it is!

Comment: If you need a specific type handling, it's common to provide specific converters, where you can test the conversion to a type with something like: `public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(ulong);`. But, since `18446744073709551615 == ulong.MaxValue`, the next safe type is `BigInteger` (you never know whether the next value can be `18446744073709551616`)

Comment: @Jimi And then where do you define the limit where it is "safe"? Then we could just as well represent everything as BigInteger. As I said, it is the same also for 18446744073709551614. Also in C# itself, if you write `var x = 18446744073709551615`, it would produce x of Type `ulong`. Since netwonsoft json is C# library, I would expect consistent behavior.

Comment: BTW, if you don't want to provide a custom converter (preferable), you can force it using this syntax: `var def = new UInt64(); string json = "18446744073709551615"; object parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<ulong>(json, def);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that [`JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string value, T anonymousTypeObject)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeAnonymousType__1.htm) doesn't quite do what you expect.  It doesn't deserialize the JSON string to the *actual type* of the `T anonymousTypeObject` argument.  It deserializes the JSON string to the ***declared type*** of the argument -- which in your case, is **`object`**.

This can be seen from the [reference source](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/release/12.0.2/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/JsonConvert.cs#L734):

```
public static T DeserializeAnonymousType<T>(string value, T anonymousTypeObject)
{
    return DeserializeObject<T>(value);
}
```

The `T anonymousTypeObject` is never actually used.  Instead the target type is entirely specified via type inference when the call to `DeserializeAnonymousType` is made -- specifically from the declared type of the variable `def` in your code.  But `def` is implicitly declared to be an `object`, because that is what [`Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.activator.createinstance?view=netframework-4.8#System_Activator_CreateInstance_System_Type_) is declared to return.  Thus `object` is what Json.NET deserializes the JSON as -- some .Net type sufficient to capture the incoming JSON.  As `BigInteger` is sufficient to capture the incoming JSON, Newtonsoft happens to choose that type instead of `Uint64`.

if you want to force Json.NET to deserialize to the actual, concrete type of a specific object, use [`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string value,Type type)`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm):

```
object parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json, def.GetType());
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wHsDFX).

Answer (score -1):

I used this example and thought that I would advance it to a list of classes:

```
List<_class> listOfClasses = new List<_class>();
var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

object parsedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(content, Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(_class)));
                        
var _listOfClasses = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<_class>>(parsedObject.ToString());

listOfClasses = _listOfClasses;
```

What this does is to consume a list of TEntity 's from an API, and then parse it back to the class it's matched against in the consumer